# Redirect everything after Sub Directory, keep URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect /acatalog/vvv-123 to /vvv-123

This is what I have in my .htaccess file at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/acatalog/([^/]+)/$ /$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand, that RewriteRules in dynamic configuration files operate in *relative* paths, in contrary to *absolute* paths that are used when defining such rules in the real http servers host configuration. That is why your rule does not get applied. This is well documented, by the way...

So you need to change

```
RewriteRule ^/acatalog/([^/]+)/$ /$1 [L]
```

to use a relative path approach, so something like

```
RewriteRule ^/?acatalog/([^/]+)/? /$1 [L]
```

Note the start and the end of the pattern change: the question mark at the start takes care that the rule gets applied on a relative *or* an absolute path, that at the end takes care that the rule also gets applied if the request does *not* end with a slash.

In general you should prefer to place such rules in the real http servers host configuration instead of relying on dynamic configuration files.